# Undefined index: inverseJoinColumns while trying to define ManyToMany relationship between two entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have two entities: User and Company and the relationship between them is n:m. In my `User.php` entity I have this code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", mappedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $companies;

public function __construct() {
    $this->companies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function setCompanies(\PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company $companies) {
    $this->companies = $companies;
}

public function getCompanies() {
    return $this->companies;
}
```

And in my `Company.php` entity I have this other code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="companies")
 */
protected $users;

public function __construct() {
    $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

But I got this error:

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: inverseJoinColumns in
>   /var/www/html/apps/portal_de_logistica/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 1041

What is wrong in the mapping?

**EDIT Refactor code**

Following instructions from @ahmed-siouani I made the following changes:

`User.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_has_company",
 *      JoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fos_user_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $companies;
```

where `fos_user_user_has_company` is the table added for the `n:m` relationship.

`Company.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="companies")
 */
protected $users;
```

And now the error is:

> AnnotationException: [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinTable
>   declared on property
>   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User::$companies does not have a
>   property named "JoinColumns". Available properties: name, schema,
>   joinColumns, inverseJoinColumns

Any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to specify the `joinColumns` and the `inverseJoinColumns` when defining the`joinTable`. For a bidirectional many-to-many definition is would be something like,

```
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Bidirectional - Many users have Many companies (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_companies",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $companies;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->companies = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

While your Company class should be defined as follow,

```
class Company
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Bidirectional (INVERSE SIDE)
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="companies")
     */
    private $users;
```

Answer (score 6):

My fault was that both sides of the ManyToMany had been defined with mappedBy, but only one side should have been using mappedBy and the other side should have used inversedBy (this is normally defined at main entity, that controls the collection).

Comment: Just to add to this, I had one side mapped m:1 and one side m:m which caused my problem. Thank you @Tobias

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ahmed solution take care of typos since I made one and for that the second error I got. See my annotation said:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_has_company",
 *      JoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fos_user_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $companies;
```

But right one is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_has_company",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fos_user_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $companies;
```

Differences are in this line:

```
joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fos_user_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
```